# Connecting to Amazon AWS PostgreSQL database from R session

Tags: r, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I have a database instance running on Amazon AWS. I use the `RPostgreSQL` package to connect my R session to my AWS database.

My issue is that every time I attempt to connect to my database instance after not having done so for a while, I get a "Connection timed out" error.

I can then use a browser to go to my AWS Console, edit the Inbound and Outbound rules for my security group to allow my IP Inbound & Outbound access. Then I can connect again just fine.

But then if I don't work on my database for a day or two, when I try to connect to my DB, it doesn't work, and the permissions for Inbound/Outbound access no longer match my IP address (which I'm sure is the cause of the problem).

So... is my IP address changing? Or are the edits I'm making to my security group's inbound/outbound permissions not being saved correctly?

To be clear, here's the order of events of how things have been going:

- Haven't worked on DB for a few days, attempt to connect from my R sessions. I get an error.
- Use browser to go to AWS Console and edit my security group's Inbound/Outbound rules by selecting "My IP"
- Try again to connect to my DB from my R session. Hooray! It works.
- A few days later - pick up the project again, attempt to reconnect to my AWS DB from R, and it no longer works...
- Repeat this cycle of madness
- Make post on SO hoping for an angel to help me

This isn't a debilitating problem, it's just extremely annoying to have to re-do my security settings every time I want to connect to my AWS DB.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Surely it's easy to tell if your IP is changing - just write down what it was when you set it and refer to it next time. Can you use a hostname rather than a ip for the security rules>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, but most possibly it seems to be that your IP is changing. Most of the ISP have Dynamic IP allocation, which means the IP can change if the router is restarted.

It is hence recommended to use DNS name instead of IP address in the security group setting.

It is easier to note down your IP address and check back after two days.
Can you see your IP address which you added two days ago in the Security Group page? If yes, you can just goto google "what is my IP" and see if both the values are same. Security Group (SG) setting does not get refreshed or changed on it's own(unless you are allocating a new Security Group).

One more thing you can try. Allow all connection (0.0.0.0) just to test. After two days or so, try again. If it works, it means there is issue with the IP address changing.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. My IP address is definitely changing (our internet sucks and we have to restart out router often). Why would using the DNS name be a better option? Is it because this is a value that won't change? For now I'll use the "all connection" option, but ideally I would like to enter something that can recognize my local machine and allow that continual access. Thanks again!

Comment: That's not possible. You can either provide IP address or the logical DNS name.  If it's your home connection or personal one, I'm afraid you don't much options apart from either entering the IP address every time it changes or using 0.0.0.0( not recommended unless its just a proof or concept or learning related). For work, usually the network has list of IP address that the outer world sees. You just have to provide all the IPs int the list into the security group.

Comment: Great, thanks Vicyan! Since it's just a side project and the security settings don't really matter at the moment, I'll use the "all connection" option. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Great. If the answer works for you, please don't forget to accept it! Thanks